# Gráfico panel data en R

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2, ggplot

Tengo el siguiente Panel Data

```
  year region                     ka_avg kao_avg
 
  1995 East Asia & Pacific        0.534   0.508 
  1995 Europe & Central Asia      0.553   0.579 
  1995 Latin America & Caribbean  0.252   0.232 
  1995 Middle East & North Africa 0.382   0.348 
  1995 North America              0.0833  0.0556
  1995 South Asia                 0.799   0.865 
  1995 Sub-Saharan Africa         0.667   0.748 
  1995 W Europe                   0.114   0.117 
  1996 East Asia & Pacific        0.465   0.416 
  1996 Europe & Central Asia      0.561   0.630
```

Necesito un gráfico como el siguiente para **ka_avg** y otro para **kao_avg**:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

donde el eje y es cada una de las variables mencionadas anteriormente y el eje X tiene la variable **year**. Las etiquetas a cada linea corresponde a **region**

Lo que tengo hecho es lo siguiente

```
ggplot(data = dataset, aes(x = year, y = ka_avg, color = region)) +
            geom_line()
```

**[image: texto en negrita]**

Me gustaría darle un aspecto similar al primero

Comment: Por lo menos deberías de compartir algún avance que has hecho. El sitio es para ayudar en complicaciones, no para hacer los quehaceres que se les encargan.

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con el aspecto?¿A la parte estética?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho exacto, a la estética

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo haría usando dos veces `geom_line()`.

La sintaxis sería la siguiente:

```
set.seed(2022)
df<-data.frame(var1=rep(2010:2020,20),
           var2=rep(LETTERS[1:20],each=11),
           var3=sample(1000:2000, 11*20,T))

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=var1,y=var3, group=var2))+
  geom_line(colour="skyblue", alpha=.4)+
  geom_line(aes(x=var1,y=var3, color=var2),
            data = df %>% filter(grepl("A|C|D|F",var2)), size=1,
            show.legend = F)+
  geom_text(aes(x=var1+.3,y=var3, label=var2),
            data = df %>% filter(grepl("A|C|D|F",var2),var1==2020))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2010,2020,1))+
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el primer `geom_line()` coloco todas las líneas y les asigno el color celeste.
Inmediatamente después agrego un `geom_line()` que solo considere a las series que me interesan, esto lo hago con un filtro `data = df %>% filter(grepl("A|C|D|F",var2))`

Para que sea similar, al que usted muestra en la imagen, se tendría que hace algunos cambios en `theme()`. Pero la estructura general sería de esa forma.